# Hibernate StaleObjectStateException

Tags: java, hibernate, exception

I have the following exception: `Caused by: org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect)`

The line that provokes exception is looking like:

```
dao.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(entity);
```

I've tried to add refresh it helped to avoid exception but data wasn't saved to db:

```
dao.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().refresh(entity);
dao.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(entity);
```

Does some workaround exists to save data without exception throwing?

Comment: may you show how you configured hibernate? are you using a threadlocal strategy for the sessionfactory?

Comment: If the data has really been updated or deleted by a different transaction, do you really want to enforce overriding it? This might lead to unexpected outcomes.

Comment: Is something other than this is modifying the row? Also, once you refresh there is no point in trying to save or update. That's trying to save what you just got from db immediately back to the db.

Comment: @AngeloImmediata yes - threadlocal strategy

Comment: @kostja the flow you have just wrote is the only possible? I mean the changes from previous transaction will be lost in all cases, yes?

Comment: Not necessarily. You can try finding the entity to determine whether it was removed. If it was removed and you want to store it again, saveOrUpdate should work. If the entity has been changed, you can merge the changes from your instance into the found instance and then save it.

Comment: @kostja so I can try to find entity using the corresponding session method and then call merge?

Comment: Hmm, I forgot about the shared cache. A simple find would probably return the stale instance from the cache. So you probably should evict the instance first: sessionFactory.evict(MyEntity.class, entity.getId()), then find it, then merge your instance. If you are using optimistic locking with @Version, you will have to update the version field on your entity to match the latest version.

Comment: @kostja I made the following: myDao.getSessionFactory().evict(MyEntity.class, entity.getId());myDao.merge(myDao.findById(entity.getId())); and this didn't help(

Comment: No no, you do not merge the newly found entity, but your instance containing the changes - this is what you want to see in the DB after all. You should also check whether find returned anythign at all.

Comment: @kostja no luck still get exception but now merge fails, the cause entity was detached so I called attachDirty before merge and still have the primary exception

Comment: Hmm I must be misunderstanding something important. Please excuse me for the fruitless efforts :(